# How to delete django background task programmatically?

Tags: django, django-views, scheduled-tasks

I have some background task which will be called when I run some function from view and the background task gets registered in the admin/database. Which works fine but what  I want is if I delete the task then the background task related with this task with`pk` should also get deleted.

How can I do it ?

tasks.py

```
@background(schedule=20)
def my_task(pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # my tasks
```

views.py

```
    def some_process():
        pk = obj.pk
        my_task(pk, repeat=3600, repeat_until='some_datetime',verbose_name="{}".format(obj.name))
    
   def delete_task():
       obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
       obj.delete()
       # while this object gets deleted I want to delete the background task related to this object
       background_task_of_this_obj= BackgroundTask.objects.get(pk=obj.pk).delete()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I deleted the both task like this.

While creating the background_task, verbose_name was based on the `obj.name` and `obj.name` was unique. So I get the background task using the verbose_name.

```
from background_task.models import Task as BTask
def delete_task():
     obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
     b_task = Btask.objects.get(verbose_name=obj.name)
     b_task.delete()
     obj.delete()
```

For this `obj.name` should be unique.